# link_to for nested resources is redirecting incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple blog app that has articles. Each article has comments. I'm trying to build nested comments using the `closure_tree` gem. I've been loosely following [this sitepoint tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/nested-comments-rails/).

I have the following code:

**models/article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :comments

end
```

**models/comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_tree order: 'created_at DESC'

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
  get 'comments/new/(:parent_id)', to: 'comments#new', as: :new_comment
end
```

**views/articles/show.html.erb**

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1><br>
<h3><%= @article.body %></h3>



Comments:
  <% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
    Title: <%= comment.title %>, Body: <%= comment.body %>, User: <%= comment.user_id %>
    <%= link_to 'reply', article_new_comment_path(parent_id: comment.id, article_id: @article.id) %>
<% end %>
</ul>


<!-- FORM FOR NEW COMMENT -->
<%= form_for ([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**views/comments/new.html.erb**

```
<%= render "form" %>
```

**views/comments/_form/html.erb**

```
<%= form_for ([@comment.article_id, @article]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**controllers/comments_controller.rb**

```
[...]
def new
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = Comment.new(parent_id: params[:parent_id])
end

def create
    # binding.pry
    if params[:comment][:parent_id].to_i > 0
    parent = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment].delete(:parent_id))
    @comment = parent.children.build(comment_params)
else
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
[...]
end
```

When I click the `link_to` in **articles/show.html.erb** in order to reply to an existing comment, I hit the `new` action as expected and pass the comment's `parent_id` and `article_id` also as expected into params.

The problem arises when I leave the `new` action. I expect to hit the form partial and then go into the `create` action for a comment. Instead I'm somehow hitting the `update` action for an `Article`, even though I don't even have one in my `ArticlesController`. I'm quite a Rails noob and I think I'm messing up in my nested routes. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I try to create an action 'subcomment' or 'child' in the controller. Something like this 'post article/:id/comments/:id/child'.

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments do
    post :child
  end
end
```

In action child something like this.

```
def child
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id]
  @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
  @child_comment = @comment.children.build(comment_params)
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

The view is other problem. Iterate over then articles.comments and comments.children and create a form with the url child_article_comment_path(@article, @comment).